# Why am I not able to access Jenkins remotely?

Tags: jenkins, remote-access

My jenkins has suddenly stopped being accessed from a remote machine. I have tried the following command to open it from another machines:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8085 --httpListenAddresss=0.0.0.0
```

and then I am tried to open it using
http://hostname:8085
And
http://ip:8085
but I am not able to access it. To launch the slave on other machine I need to have access to that url.

note: I am able to ping to my host name from any remote machine. 
I given access to all inbound and outbound connections from my firewall

Answer (score 0):

You can see the correct URL in Nodes view:

- Create dummy node with "Launch method" = "Launch agent via Java Web Start"
- Save it
- Choose this 'dummy' node
- Jenkins should show you a command line with correct URL, i.e.

`java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://myjenkinsserver:8080/computer/dummy/slave-agent.jnlp -secret c159219e557d0e612371b97d86f9a319584cf1c53b8ab9df73f34b46eed8865c`

Comment: To launch the slave the link http://myjenkinsserver:8080/ should be visible remotely.

Comment: Yes, definitely. You want to say that you can't access to Jenkins Web interface?

Comment: yah, I am not able to access jenkins interface remotely

Comment: So, how do you know that jenkins service is up and running? If the service is running, disable firewall (temporary) on both computers - server and slave

Comment: by disabling the firewall it is working but that is not the preferable way

Comment: nice. It means you should learn how to configure your firewalls. The issue is not related to Jenkins at all